# Max sum from two arrays picking one element from each such that their index differs by 3

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am looking to improve the efficiency of a (python) problem from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`. The problem is like this, I have two arrays `k=[11,11,13,11,12,15]` and `l=[7,5,10,9,5,9,11]`. I want to find `max sum` by picking one element from each array and index of elements from each array should differ by 3.

For the above two arrays, it should give me a sum of 24. The brute force solution I can think of is to iterate through the both the lists in a Cartesian way which gives efficiency as `O(n^2)`. Below is my code.

```
max=0
    for i in range(len(array_k)):
        for j in range(len(array_l)):
            if (array_k[i]+array_l[j])>max and abs(i-j)>=3:
                max=array_k[i]+array_l[j]


return   max
```

Please let me know how to improve this problem efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it should give me a sum of 24

Actually 25, but anyway I think I got **N log N** solution:

```
array_k = [11, 11, 13, 11, 12, 15]
array_l = [7, 5, 10, 9, 5, 9, 11]

new_k = [(pos, val, True) for pos, val in enumerate(array_k)]
new_l = [(pos, val, False) for pos, val in enumerate(array_l)]

r = new_k + new_l

r.sort(key=lambda el: el[1], reverse=True)

first_pos = r[0][0]
first_val = r[0][1]
first_type = r[0][2]

for i in range(1, len(r)):
    pos, value, type_ = r[i]
    if type_ is not first_type and abs(pos - first_pos) >= 3:
        print("MAX = ", first_val + value)
        break
```

Let me know if u need further explanation.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed one solution of N LogN